# How to reflect a nested delegate in C#?

Tags: c#, reflection, delegates

Given the following (minimal) class:

```
public class TestEvents
{
    public delegate void MyDelegate(params string[] data);

    public TestEvents()
    {
    }
}
```

If I retrieve the `Type` object representing this class from an assembly how can I identify all nested delegates defined in this class? I can find a lot of information how to invoke a delegate via reflection, but nothing on how to obtain a suitable object from a `Type` object in the beginning (*without* knowing the delegates name).

Answer (score 1):

You have to loop through the nested types and test if they are derived from `MulticastDelegate`.

```
var delegates = typeof(TestEvents).GetNestedTypes().Where(x => x.BaseType == typeof(MulticastDelegate));
foreach(var del in delegates)
    Console.WriteLine(del.Name);
```

Comment: That's exactly what I wanted to know. Is there no better way than to do it like this? There are dozens of convenience methods for everything, for methods, for constructors, for properties, for fields and everything. But not for delegates? Seems like that - and you might think of it different, but I find it a bit strange. But anyway: Thank you for your reply.

Comment: I think delegates are just normal types in terms of metadata.